# How to add input value as a tag to an object array and display it in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

How can I add a key value to an object array? I'm Fetching an api and want to add value to a particular student/person array from user's input.
Let's say we click on the first list's input and we type xyz the it should add a tag: 'xyz' and then if we add abc then it has to be tag: ['xyz', 'abc'].Im toatlly new to react so pardon me if somethings terribly wrong.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
export default class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {


  state = {
    loading: true,
    people: [],
    input: '',
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ people: data.students, loading: false });
    //
  }

  onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loadin) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.people.length) {
      return <div>didnt get person...</div>;
    }

    const list = this.state.people.filter(person => this.state.input.toLowerCase() === '' || person.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.input.toLowerCase()) || person.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.input.toLowerCase()))
    .map(person => (
      <div key={person.id}>
        <li>
          {JSON.stringify(person.firstName)}
          {JSON.stringify(person.lastName)}
          {/*want to add newTag value for particular person in list */}
          <input type="text" />
          {/* and display it here */}
        </li>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="example1">
          {/* this input will search and filter person based on first and last name */}
          <input value={this.state.input} type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)} />
          <ul>{list}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you also write what type error you receive?

Comment: Hey @DenizKaradağ I have not received any error with this code, I just need a suggestion  for the output.

Answer (score 0):

In case I understand your question correctly, this is one of the ways that you can add a key value to your object:

```
var obj ={ a: 1, b: 2 };
obj.c = 5  
console.log(obj);
output  
Object { a: 1, b: 2, c: 5 }
```

since you want to do this for a specific student, there should be a logic to find the correct student first. so you have to loop over your students array.

```
const data = [your array]
const updatedData = data.map(student =>{
if (student.id === person.id) {// you need to use the correct key names here
student = {... student,
 tag: "xyz" // this xyz comes from you input, you need to adjust here
}
}
return student
})
```

after that you can render correct data. Keep in mind, I just wrote how to update an array just one time. Since you are using react, you need to apply this logic to update your state. So every-time there is an update, also state should get updated.

Comment: Hey, @Deniz Yes, I partially like this, but I still want something where it can only add to the specific array. So let's say we have 3 students and we add the input in the 2nd student array and click enter then only that student should have that value.

Comment: Logic is already there. At the part student.id === person.id. That's where you find the right student. person.id comes from your rendered elements. that's where you have your input data. student.id is your original data in state. 
So you collect the data from input field of this person, then you find this person in the state by matching the ids. then you copy all data of that person with spread operator{...student}. then you add a  tag  field in the object. If you want it to be an array, then you say:
 student = {... student,
 tag: ["xyz"]
}
or if you want say student.tag.push("xyz")